# Typescript overloading a class method. Method X should return object type Y or Z, based on object parameter type A or B

Tags: typescript, overloading

I'm trying to overload a class method inside a class, such that it always takes in 1 argument, an object of type A or B. Based on that parameter, the expected return type should be Y or Z.

What is the correct way in the implementation of the method to specify/check the argument so that the (rest of the program knows / method knows) to have the correct type returned from method x?

```
interface Argument1 {
 argOnePropOne: string
 argOnePropTwo: string
 argOnePropThree: string
}

interface Argument2 {
 argTwoPropOne: number
 argTwoPropTwo: string
}

interface Response1 {
 responseOnePropOne: number
}

interface Response2 {
 responseTwoPropOne: string
 responseTwoPropTwo: bool
}

type UnionArg = Argument1 | Argument2
type UnionResponse = Response1 | Response2

//I want to tell typescript, if we receive Argument1, that the return type will be Response1, likewise for Argument2
interface xClassInterface {
  x(arg: Argument1): Response1
  x(arg: Argument2): Response2
}

class X implements xClassInterface {
 x(arg: UnionArg): UnionResponse {
   //Return either something in the shape of Response1 or Response2, but complains
   //With "Call signature return types Response1 and Response2 are incompatible. The 
   //types of Data are incompatible between these types." 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your overloadings directly above the method:

```js
interface Argument1 {
    argOnePropOne: string
    argOnePropTwo: string
    argOnePropThree: string
}

interface Argument2 {
    argTwoPropOne: number
    argTwoPropTwo: string
}

interface Response1 {
    responseOnePropOne: number
}

interface Response2 {
    responseTwoPropOne: string
    responseTwoPropTwo: boolean
}

type UnionArg = Argument1 | Argument2
type UnionResponse = Response1 | Response2


class X {
    x(arg: Argument1): Response1
    x(arg: Argument2): Response2
    x(arg: UnionArg): UnionResponse {
        return null as any
    }
}

const result = new X()

const foo = result.x(null as any as Argument1) // Response1
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJQOYFcC2FwCMyA3gFDIXJyYDyIEAClAPYAOdEAXMgM5hSgM5StQwcmbACoB3Ztz4CQQylVr0JrSQAsoELr36DSAX1KlQkWIhTpsecACYSwiqJnMNHbiFwAjaC6qGO4a7vKGSiZmFtDwSMgAShA8rMwgPBBEZCq6KWkZ4izs9N5%20Aabm4LHWicmp6RBO2ZS59RkhRV4GisotdfkQHVKy3L7MzAA2EHAgUaRgAJ6sKACqIMBptsgAvGiYuPhgRAA%20e3aHDvNLq%20tpSXkNO7UPGSfPbY1mpAgTcDw8yAAGs4VAAPAAUom4tgOhAAlNx7h8CIEIVCzrCwA4Ee8BpcwZDMNw1hsQLYcSS7v1Hs0VBRdGAsFAQMgfBMJlQATMFoFTBUEPkwMhclgJkLdvRpEDwXCzAL0kKYOMniKxQA6CFsjl-KggBacjH2I5w5AAelNuIaBCAA)

Thanks **@kaya3**:

> Method signatures are never inherited from interfaces

Also, there is another workaround how to use overloadings with method:

```js
interface Argument1 {
    argOnePropOne: string
    argOnePropTwo: string
    argOnePropThree: string
}

interface Argument2 {
    argTwoPropOne: number
    argTwoPropTwo: string
}

interface Response1 {
    responseOnePropOne: number
}

interface Response2 {
    responseTwoPropOne: string
    responseTwoPropTwo: boolean
}

type UnionArg = Argument1 | Argument2
type UnionResponse = Response1 | Response2


//I want to tell typescript, if we receive Argument1, that the return type will be Response1, likewise for Argument2
interface xClassInterface {
    (arg: Argument1): Response1
    (arg: Argument2): Response2
}


class X {
    x: xClassInterface = (arg: UnionArg) => {
        return null as any
    }
}

const result = new X()

const foo = result.x(null as any as Argument1) // Response1
const bar = result.x(null as any as Argument2) // Response2
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJQOYFcC2FwCMyA3gFDIXJyYDyIEAClAPYAOdEAXMgM5hSgM5StQwcmbACoB3Ztz4CQQylVr0JrSQAsoELr36DSAX1KlQkWIhTpsecACYSwiqJnMNHbiFwAjaC6qGO4a7vKGSiZmFtDwSMgAShA8rMwgPBBEZCq6KWkZ4izs9N5%20Aabm4LHWicmp6RBO2ZS59RkhRV4GisotdfkQHVKy3L7MzAA2EHAgUaRgAJ6sKACqIMBptsgAvGiYuPhgRAA%20e3aHDvNLq%20tpSXkNO7UPGSfPbY1mpAD03wCSyGkMzAyDAzFBEAmE1B1x4CAErDAABpkMAYICULokMAAG42fb2I4osBaOAgkmYiBgLBQEAw5aA4BQ5D%20d4DAgoibAADWEGkwAyyBgzCgZwOjkqljiKAAHgBhCZwHg8P5VKzxZoUAAUom4tnFRwAlNx7h8CIEdZg9QSLsa2Q1LhVSAhFcrkAANZwqGXceWulVq6VPS0YbhrDYgWyGnYAPi9Kj61NpyB8zKVVBAC0CpgqCHyINyWAmIN29GkHq1hrMefSIOF4N2heLADoZVrU9D0zMFlQeGLCQRo797a9nfmWdQnk2wK320XO33u73%207bkMPTQMHEA)

Comment: This is amazing, thank you. Can you give me a brief explanation of why your solution works, but my ```class X implements xClassInterface``` doesn't? Seemingly my interface declares the overloads exactly as your overloads above the method, no?

Comment: @Brandon6 Method signatures are never inherited from interfaces, even when you don't have overloads. If you write `class X implements Y` then it only checks that that's true, it doesn't assume that it's true and therefore infer anything about `X`.

Comment: @kaya3 thank you for explanation.

Comment: @Brandon6 made an update with alternative approach